# Bootstrap carousel. Hide 'previous' and 'next' buttons on first and last slide - 'slide' event not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this standard Bootstrap carousel:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>App Preview</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Contact Details</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Choose plan</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            4
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        @*<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>*@
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        @*<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>*@
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to hide the 'previous' and 'next' buttons respectively, if the user is on the first or last items of the carousel:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false,
})

$('#myCarousel').on('slid', '', checkitem);

function checkitem()                        // check function
{
    var $this = $('#myCarousel');
    if ($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')) {
        $this.children('.left.carousel-control').hide();
    } else if ($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')) {
        $this.children('.right.carousel-control').hide();
    } else {
        $this.children('.carousel-control').show();

    }
}
```

It doesn't work though. When I debug using the Chrome developer tools, I can see the event being hooked up, but the breakpoint in the actual checkitem() code is never hit, so I'm not sure if the debugger just doesn't work when events are triggered or if the event is never being triggered.

(I'm including the following scripts)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the full script to get this working fully, not just after the slide is triggered. As pointed out by Mihai, for some reason I need to use the slid.bs.carousel event not 'slid':

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false,
})

$(document).ready(function () {               // on document ready
    checkitem();
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', checkitem);

function checkitem()                        // check function
{
    var $this = $('#myCarousel');
    if ($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')) {
        // Hide left arrow
        $this.children('.left.carousel-control').hide();
        // But show right arrow
        $this.children('.right.carousel-control').show();
    } else if ($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')) {
        // Hide right arrow
        $this.children('.right.carousel-control').hide();
        // But show left arrow
        $this.children('.left.carousel-control').show();
    } else {
        $this.children('.carousel-control').show();
    }
}
```

Carousel events documentation - getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', checkitem);
```

But this will hide your buttons only when a "slid" event occurs. It works well for the last "next" but it doesn't hide the first "previous". To hide the first "previous" you could use CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/0bwnqahj/1/

Comment: Thanks Mihai. I've added my own answer that includes how to hide previous and next when the document first loads. Where did you find out that you need to use slid.bs.carousel? I've been looking for carousel documentation but couldn't find a full list of methods etc.

Comment: You're welcome Chris. Here is the link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

Answer (score 0):

Try Slick slider https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. It has almost every feature. Including button disable, customization and responsive.

In button disable case, you need to `infinite: false` option of slick slider

Comment: This may contain answer to the question, but try to add explanation also.

Answer (score -1):

Some years old, but Bootstrap's carousel is still valuable I suppose.

Chris' answer is good, it only misses the case when there is only 1 item to show (would still show the right arrow then). Also, we could use jQuery's toggle function that takes a boolean parameter to spare the ifs.

The more precise and shorter solution would then be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    checkControls();
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', checkControls);

// Hide left / right control if carousel is at first / last position.
function checkControls() {
    var $this = $('#profilepicsCarousel');
    $this.children('.carousel-control-prev').toggle(
        !$this.find('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:first-child').hasClass('active')
    );
    $this.children('.carousel-control-next').toggle(
        !$this.find('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:last-child' ).hasClass('active')
    );
}
```